# How do I take an user input from Scanner in one class and then apply it to another class in the same package?

Tags: java

For example

package testcircle1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCircle1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome!!!!");
    Circle c1 = new Circle( );
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Please enter a number");

    c1.setRadius() = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(c1.getRadius()); 

}
```

}

package testcircle1;
public class Circle {

```
public Circle() {   
}

public Circle(double radius) {

}

public void setRadius(double radius) {
    if (radius >= 0)
        this.radius = radius;
}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This `c1.setRadius() = in.nextDouble();` should be `c1.setRadius(in.nextDouble());`

Comment: One more question. Say you want to add exceptions to both codes. How will I get go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below two.
1. Add 'private double radius;' in class Circle
2. In main method you need to use c1.setRadius(in.nextDouble())

providing code for the same

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCircle1 {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCircle1.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
System.out.println("Welcome!!!!");
Circle c1 = new Circle();

try {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter a number");

  if (!in.hasNextDouble()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is not a double value");
  }

  c1.setRadius(in.nextDouble());

  System.out.println(c1.getRadius());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

}
}

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;
    public Circle() {
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {

    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        if (radius >= 0)
            this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

}
```

Comment: One more question. Say you want to add IllegalArgumentExceptions to both codes. How will I go about it? Struggling to do that

Comment: I have updated the code above to handle IllegalArgumentException which will be thrown when user enter any value other than double. It need to be added in the TestCircle1 class in this case.